# In Slack, how do I find out how many messages per month per channel?

Tags: slack, statistics, zapier

I'm the Slack admin. I want to replace a home-grown Slack integration with Zapier. But to know which Zapier tier to buy, I need to know historically how many messages were posted to a given Slack channel per month.

I've looked all through Slack's Statistics page, admin interface and client UI and cannot find this specific metric.

Is it gettable?

Answer (score -1):

See the article, [Review team activity and statistics](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/218407447-Review-team-activity-and-statistics) for instructions to do this.  Note that the article states:

> Who can use this feature?
>
> - By default, all members except for Guests can view team activity.
> - Available to teams on the Standard and Plus plans, but a limited report is available on the Free plan.

Comment: As I wrote, I read through their Statistics page and it does not contain the information I need. It does not show messages broken down per channel.

Comment: The Limited report is that a free Slack Team will on'y show the breakdown of public / private / PM.

Comment: We're not on a free plan. We're on the Standard plan.